# cascade gallery widget like viewpager in android

Tags: android, android-viewpager, gallery

I want to achieve this effect above in android.
I google it,but it's nothing useful.Who can give me a tips,thank you.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ma260.png)

Comment: Please check the [formatting help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) and include your image properly.

Comment: Thanks for your tips,I'll pay attention next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its called a Carousel.

Use [this](https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidImageSlider) library in your project to achieve this kind of effect.

Comment: Thank you very much.This is my first question in stackoverflow,it's awesome.

Comment: I find daimajia's library isn's my need effect.Carousel library is my need.But i don't found some source code about Carousel ,only jar.Do you have any solutions?

Comment: You need to add that library to your project, there are many ways using jar or using gradle. Follow these steps, go to that link again, scroll down to usage, copy all the four lines that has `compile` prefix after that in your Android Studio find gradle(app) file from the left hand side project explorer, it will have dependencies section paste all four lines in that section. DO NOT REMOVE ANY OTHER LINES. After that you will see `Sync now` on top right click it wait a few seconds and you added the library :)
Now visit this link https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidImageSlider/wiki for tutorials